# Button not clicked in React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am a new learner and have only been developing for about 4 months now on react. I was building a simple portfolio for myself and came in to a error.
I have created a toggler and a button and kept them in navbar. But it is not being clicked no matter how hard i try.
I have attached some coes for the button and the toggler.
Note: The toggler is a dark and light theme switcher and the button is just a regular button that downloads resume(i havenot uploaded the files yet.)

The code is below

```
function App() {
  const style =
    "block max-w-sm p-6 bg-white-50 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 w-50 sm:w-50";

  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  function handleCheck() {
    setChecked(!checked);
  }

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setMode(mode === "light" ? "dark" : "light");
  };

  return (
    <div className={mode === "dark" ? "dark" : ""}>
      <ScrollContainer>
        <section className="h-screen w-screen bg-orange-50 dark:bg-gray-900">
          <nav className="p-8 mb-12 flex justify-between  sm:text-left">
            <h1 className="text-xl space-x-5 dark:text-white">
              Developed by, <span className=" text-teal-500">__RSD</span>
            </h1>
            <ul className="flex items-center dark:text-white space-x-5">
              <label className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={mode === "dark"}
                  className="sr-only peer"
                  onChange={handleCheck}
                />
                <div
                  onClick={toggleDarkMode}
                  className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer  peer-focus:ring-green-300  peer-checked:after:translate-x-full
                   peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute
                    after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border 
                   after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-gray-600"
                ></div>
                <span className="ml-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white text-black">
                  Dark
                </span>
              </label>

              <li>
                <button>
                  <a
                    href="/assets/RajuSharma.pdf"
                    download
                    className=" bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white hover:text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
                  >
                    Resume
                  </a>
                </button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div className="p-5 text-center text-black dark:text-white">
            <motion.h2
              className="font-mono font-bold mt-52 text-5xl tracking-widest "
              initial={{ x: "100%" }}
              animate={{ x: "0%" }}
              transition={{ duration: 1 }}
            >
              RAJU SHARMA DAHAL
            </motion.h2>
            <motion.h3
              className="font-mono font-semibold text-3xl tracking-widest"
              initial={{ x: "-100%" }}
              animate={{ x: "0%" }}
              transition={{ duration: 1.5 }}
            >
              <span className=" text-teal-500">WEB</span> DEVELOPER
            </motion.h3>
            <div className="flex justify-center">
              <p className="font-serif pt-4 text-black text-center leading-3f w-2/4 dark:text-white">
                As a front-end developer, I am passionate about creating
                visually appealing and user-friendly websites. I have experience
                in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and I enjoy using these skills to
                bring designs to life.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="text-center text-3xl font-bold"></div>
          <div className="flex text-xl tracking-wide justify-center gap-6 pt-5">
            <a
              className="text-black dark:text-white"
              href="https://github.com/razzuSharma"
            >
              <BsGithub />
            </a>
            <a
              className="text-black dark:text-white"
              href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/raju-sharma-6a30671b0/"
            >
              <BsLinkedin />
            </a>
            <a
              className="text-black dark:text-white"
              href="https://www.facebook.com/ribekon/"
            >
              <BsFacebook />
            </a>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="h-screen w-screen  bg-orange-50  dark:bg-gray-900">
          <ScrollPage>
            <Skills />
            <section className=" dark:bg-gray-900">
              <Projects />
            </section>
          </ScrollPage>
        </section>
        <section className="bg-orange-50  dark:bg-gray-900">
          <Contact />
        </section>
      </ScrollContainer>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I was expecting to toggle the button or atleast the button to be clicked or change the cursor on hover.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using tailwindcss to style the dark mode, make sure you include this in your `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  // ...
}
```

Refer to [this page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually).

Comment: I have done it and i want to add that "whenever i make my website mobile view and change it to the laptop view from the devtools the buttons work for one time and doesnot work the second time after i refresh it"

Comment: @RajuSharmaDahal Then it seems like your code works perfectly, I tested the button and toggle function and didn't see any issue, maybe something is blocking from other components.

Comment: Did you click the check button to toggle the dark mode or the gray rounded button?

Comment: Yeah both the buttons are working fine when you are changing the view from mobile to laptop view from the devtools and it works sometimes only

Comment: @XH thank you brother there was a problem in another component i imported.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Your code is hard to follow especially if you don't provide a portion of the navbar.

I'll try to try answer your problem based on my guts:

> What I noticed is your `click` event is created on a `div` but your
> label is outside of it.

Maybe when you click on something, but you're not actually clicking the triggering event of the click. Could you try, putting your label inside of the click event?

Another thing to note:

- You're creating a 2 states in your app for handling the theme:
  `checked` and `mode`. This cause a bad performance in your app since
  your component will render twice because of this. You can just use
  single state to mark your app either `dark` or `light`
- Since you're creating a portfolio and it's public facing website, it's also important to follow Semantic HTML. In reality, only clickable elements are button and href, we should use them in all cases as it's important for accessibility. Though, you can use elements to bind an even but I would suggest to still follow the semantic HTML.
- You're breaking your unordered list because you created a label inside of it without wrapping them in `li`.

Please let me know if it solves your problem I pointed above. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion "About trigerring the event, the event gets triggered sometimes when i resize the view port from mobile to the laptop screen(that is full)" and i can toggle the dark and light theme as well as the button of the Resume works too.

Comment: I got the solution, the above code i provided was fine there was a issue with the other component that I imported 

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that the button is missing an `onClick` handler, which is why it is not doing anything when clicked.

Also, it is not recommended to nest interactive elements, so if you want a link that looks like a button, you should remove the outer `button` element and simply style the `a` element like a button (which you already seem to be doing)

The cursor can be controlled by adding the `cursor-pointer` tailwind utility to your classes

Your dark mode toggle will not work since the `toggleDarkMode` method captures the value of `mode` at first render and doesn't update. You can use `useCallback` to make sure the method updates:

```
const toggleDarkMode = useCallback(() => {
  setMode(mode === "light" ? "dark" : "light");
}, [mode]);
```

Comment: Excellenct, but toggle dark mode is not working and i have added other buttons in the navbar section and none of them works.

Comment: I've added an extra paragraph for the dark mode toggling